# Zero solution for integer programming

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R programming. I am trying to do integer programming in R. I am getting output as 0 for all the decision variables when I use `int.vec`. Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening. Following is my code.

```
library(lpSolve)
f.obj=c(900,900,900,900,1800,1800,1800,1800)
f.con=matrix(c(3,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,                                                                       
    0,3,0,0,0,6,0,0,                                                                       
    0,0,3,0,0,0,6,0,                                                                       
    0,0,0,3,0,0,0,6,                                                                       
    1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,                                                                       
    0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,                                                                       
    0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,                                                                       
    0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,                                                                       
    0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,                                                                       
    0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,                                                                       
    0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,                                                                       
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,                                                                       
    1/13,1/19,1/24,1/15,0,0,0,0,                                                           
    0,0,0,0,1/13,1/19,1/24,1/15), ncol=8, byrow=TRUE)
f.dir=c("=","=","=","=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=","<=")
f.rhs=c(2500,500,2500,500,650,1200,800,1200,650,1200,800,1200,100,100)
solution=lp("max",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,int.vec = 1:8)
solution$solution
```

Output:

```
#[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting all zeros because it is the only "integer" solution. The solution status=2, meaning the problem is infeasible. If we do not require the first four variables to be integer, the solution is non-zero:

```
solution=lp(direction = "max",f.obj,f.con,f.dir,f.rhs,int.vec = 5:8)

> solution$solution
[1]   1.3333333   0.6666667   1.3333333   0.6666667 416.0000000  83.0000000
[7] 416.0000000  83.0000000
```